# Is $(Ax, x) = 0 \implies A=0$ True/false

Tags: linear-algebra

Is  following statements is  true/false?

> If $A \in \mathbb{M_n}(\mathbb{R})$ is such that $(Ax, x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n $ then $A = 0$

**My attempt** :  I think  this  statement is true

Take $ Ax=\lambda x$ then

$(Ax, x) =(\lambda x,x)=\lambda||x||^2=0 \implies\lambda=0$

take  $\lambda=\lambda_k=0 $ where $n=1,2,3,,,n$

Thus ,$A$  is   similar  to null matrix therefore $A=0$

Comment: How about $A(x,y)=(-y,x)$?

Comment: Im not  getting @KaviRamaMurthy  can you elaborate  more ?

Comment: matrix proposed by @KaviRamaMurthy is not diagonalizable

Comment: To rephrase @KaviRamaMurthy's solution: take $n=2$, $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ and with $x=(u,v)^T$, we have $(Ax, x)=au^2+(b+c)uv+dv^2$. This will be identically zero if $a=0, b+c=0, d=0$, which *does not* imply that $a=b=c=d=0$: just take $a=0, b=1, c=-1, d=0$. You can extend this argument to any size matrix: you can prove that $A+A^T=0$, but not that $A=0$.

Comment: To clarify further. Kavi’s example is a clear counterexample. The $90^\circ$ rotation matrix $A$ always has $(Ax,x)=0$ for real vectors $x$ in two dimensions, but $A\neq0$. Your argument fails for this matrix since $A$ doesn’t have real eigenvalues.

Comment: Kavi's linear transformation will get you an orthogonal vector to x, so the inner product of x and Ax is zero always without A being 0

Comment: @StinkingBishop im not  getting  how  you got that $(Ax,x)=au^2 +(b+c)uv  +dv^2?$

Comment: If I understand your symbols/conventions correctly, $Ax=(au+bv, cu+dv)^T$ so $(Ax, x)=(au+bv )u+(cu+dv)v=au^2+(b+c)uv+dv^2$.

Comment: okay @StinkingBishop  Got it thanks you

Comment: The statement is true in the complex case, i e. $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C}).$